# left align text on setting Label width

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a label inside a grid with a fixed width like this:

```
Label(popup,text="Testing",width=25,justify="left").grid(row=1,column=1,sticky="w",padx=(0,10),pady=10)
```

[image]

I need the text to align to the left and hide the overflow if any occurs,
How do I achieve this?

Comment: You could use ```anchor="w"``` instead of ```justify="left"``` to align the text to the left.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify an [`anchor`](https://tkdocs.com/shipman/anchors.html) option when creating the [`Label`](https://tkdocs.com/shipman/label.html) widget:

```
from tkinter import *

popup = Tk()

Label(popup, text="Testing", width=25, anchor="w").grid(
        row=1, column=1, sticky="w", padx=(0,10), pady=10)

popup.mainloop()
```

Result:

[image: Screenshot]